# Sleep Function not working. Declaration?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\1\Pc - S.txt", "Pc - S - A.txt")
Sleep(2000)
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\Users\mario\Desktop\Dominio\1\Pc - S - A.txt", "Pc - S.txt")
```

But when i run it, it appears this error message:

```
Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\mario\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe'.
Additional Information: A call to PInvoke function 'WindowsApplication1!WindowsApplication1.Form1::Sleep' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.
```

What is hapening? I use this to declare it: `Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

What is hapening and how do I fix it? I assume is the declaration..

SOLUTION:   Just use this: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
            It does not use a declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration is wrong, the Sleep() argument is `Integer`, not Long.  Watch out for old VB6 declarations you find in various web pages, almost anything that uses Long is wrong for VB.NET.  The VB6 types were based on its 16-bit version, VB4 was the last one.

Just don't do this and use the [.NET method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @SpectralGhost way is working. I went to your link and copied the declaration directly and it did not work. Do i have to change the declaration?

Comment: The link is *not* a declaration, it just shows you how to call it.  Just like you used RenameFile() without a declaration.  Spelled out in full, it is System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

Comment: In the link:
'Declaration   <----
Public Shared Sub Sleep ( _
 millisecondsTimeout As Integer _
)

Oh i see it works without declaring, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal Milliseconds As Integer)
```

You should pay special attention to type declarations. Longs are bigger than they used to be in VB6, so you need to make sure any code you get off the web is right for your current environment.